# How to display a list in flask without brackets? (by using jinja2 batch)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to display a list in flask where every two items of a list are printed on a new row.

```
{% for x in sources| batch(2) %}
    <h2>{{ sources}} </h2>
    {% endfor %}
```

This works, but the items are displayed with brackets and quotes  e.g. ['rain', 8.0].
I want to display them like rain : 8.0 
How do i get rid of those brackets and quotes?

Edit: The sources list is: ['Decibel', 5, 'People', 3, 'Temperature', 2, 'Rain', 8, 'Time', 21].
I want to display it as Decibel, 5 and then on the next row People, 3 etc.

I also tried

```
  {% for x in range(0, sources|length,2) %}
    <h2>{{ sources[x],sources[x+1] }} </h2>
    {% endfor %}
```

but then the quotes and brackets are also displayed.

This code below does not print the brackets and quotes, but only displays one item per row.

`{% for x in sources %}
    <h2>{{ x }} </h2>
      {% endfor %}`

Comment: This problem probably relates to the python code which generates `sources`.  Can you add that to the question?

Comment: added it in the edit, the sources list was originally a list of tuples, but i made it a list by doing a list comprehension [x for y in sources for x in y].

Comment: Can you post the code that originally generates this data?  The batch filter is meant for displaying stuff in a grid easily.  A close fix might be: `{% for x in sources| batch(2) %}<h2>{% for col in x %}{{col}}:{% endfor %}</h2>{% endfor %}` however this leaves you with a trailing colon in your output: `Decibel: 5:`.  It may be easier to compile the datastructure differently, rather than trying to hack this together at the template level.

Comment: It is kind of hard to show the code that generates this data, since the data is generated from a lot of different functions and each function returns the name and a number. I put the results of all those functions into a list of tuples, but then it was even harder to display them properly (I am not an expert at python). Is there a smarter way than to store them into tuples or lists?

Comment: Thanks tho, i tried your method and it does come close enough, i can remove the colon and then it looks cleaner than any method i've tried before. This is what it looks like now https://imgur.com/d8I2roN

Comment: See the answer someone else has put here.  probably better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only use 2 elements

```
<h2> {{ x[0] }}: {{ x[1] }} </h2>
```

Or you can use:

```
{{ x|join(':') }}
```

it looks like the python join